# Can using parallel hint improve performance of query on specified partition of table?

Tags: oracle, performance, parallel-processing, query-optimization, partition

Does it work when I query specified partition table using parallel hint?

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(A,5)*/
    A.USER_ID
     , A.RES_TYPE
     , A.RES_ID
     , A.LIMIT_TAG
     , A.FEEPOLICY_INS_ID
     , A.FEEPOLICY_ID
     , TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(A.START_DATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) AS START_DATE
     , TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(A.END_DATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) AS END_DATE
FROM   TF_B_USER_FREECDR_HASH PARTITION(PAR_TF_B_USER_FREECDR_0) A
ORDER  BY A.USER_ID
```

Here is the explain plan:

[image: picture of the explain plan]

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar can the sql statements imporve performance using parallel,thanks

Comment: but i query specified partition table

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "yes".  There's very little difference between a partition and a table, they are both segments and can be easily parallelized.  If that partition really is over 800MB large then parallelism will almost certainly help with a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

> "can the sql statements imporve performance using parallel"

Yes. Or no. Or, indeed, performance could deteriorate. It really depends on so many factors.

For instance, how many processors (CPU cores) does your server have? How many are available for use? There's no benefit to using parallel hints if you don't have the CPUs available; in fact the overhead of managing parallel execution could cause a slower outcome.

Why did you choose degree of parallel 5? Unless you can guarantee having five available CPUs to run five threads simultaneously you will have threads hanging doing nothing while other threads are running. Powers of two make more sense (2, 4, 8, etc).

> "the cpu count is 120"

That's how many you might be able to use. Depending on the actual workload you might not be able to grab five when you need them. However, the odds are pretty good.

Now, as to whether parallel will make any difference to your actually query, it's hard for us to tell. The explain plan shows that the optimizer will attempt a parallel execution but doesn't show whether you'll get benefits from it.

Obviously, all things being equal, splitting a big job into several streams and running them concurrently should result in a reduced total elapsed time. Things don't always work out that way. So, try benchmarking your statement, with and without parallel hint. Query `V$PQ_TQSTAT` to see what happens. (You may need your friendly DBA to grant you privileges on that view.)

Comment: the cpu count is 120